# Using Spark ML's Logistic Regression model on MultiClass Classification giving error : Column prediction already exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I am using Spark ML's Logistic Regression model for classification problem having 100 categories (0-99). My columns in dataset are - "_c0,_c1,_c2,_c3,_c4,_c5"
where _c5 is a target variable and rest are the features. My code is following :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.OneVsRest
val _c0Indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("_c0").setOutputCol("_c0Index")
val _c1Indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("_c1").setOutputCol("_c1Index")
val _c2Indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("_c2").setOutputCol("_c2Index")
val _c3Indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("_c3").setOutputCol("_c3Index")
val _c4Indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("_c4").setOutputCol("_c4Index")
val _c5Indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("_c5").setOutputCol("_c5Index")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("_c0Index", "_c1Index", "_c2Index", "_c3Index","_c4Index")).setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8).setLabelCol("_c5Index").setFeaturesCol("features")
val ovr = new OneVsRest().setClassifier(lr)
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(_c0Indexer, _c1Indexer, _c2Indexer, _c3Indexer, _c4Indexer,assembler, _c5Indexer, ovr,lr))
val model = pipeline.fit(data)
val predictions = model.transform(testdf)
println(predictions.select("features", "_c5Index", "probability","prediction").show(5))
```

But it is showing an error :

```
requirement failed: Column prediction already exists.
```

Can someone please guide why I am getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I came to know that Spark ML's Logistic Regression is used for binary classification only. So, to use it for multi class classification, we have to use OneVsRest Strategy. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: can you provide sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out the "lr" at the end of your pipeline. I think it's unnecessary since ovr uses lr.